# What type of arduino board do I need?

Tags: arduino, power, serial, signal

I need some help with choosing an Arduino board or maybe something else for the task that I need to do.

I want to have a board that will get a input (power signal) to the board and that will send a some sort of signal through the COM port to my PC.

What do I need to achieve that? You got any examples?

This will be used for example when you switch the light on and then I need to send a message to my pc that light is on.

Please give me some links and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think people aren't helping you because they think that you could have just googled for the answer.

Anyways, here's a project that uses an Arduino to monitor voltage and current for a section of home wiring: http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/58

If you don't care about power consumption monitoring but just on/off, you can leave out the half of that project that does voltage measurement, and only implement the current measurement half.

Comment: hmm, I did googled on the internet but didn't find anything similar with what I need. I thought that someone has made something similar already... thank's for the answer